# cordova.file.dataDirectory not creating file inside the app folder

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Downloading images using `cordova.file` into `dataDirectory`. I am saving files into internal app folder. In the emulator I am able to see the downloaded files but on real device I am not able to see the downloaded file. This is my path look like

[image]
not able to see this image into app folder.

```
$scope.Download = function () {
            var FileURL = appService.downloadFiles($scope.selectedFile.FileKey);
            var targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "ChatApp/" + $scope.selectedFile.FileName;
            var trustHosts = true;
            var options = {};
            $cordovaFileTransfer.download(FileURL, targetPath, options, trustHosts)
                  .then(function (result) {
                      alert('file downloaded successfully');
                      console.log(result);
                      refreshMedia.refresh(targetPath);
                  }, function (err) {                      
                      console.log(err);
                  }, function (progress) {
                      console.log(progress);                      
                  });

        };       
    }
```

Does it required any permission to create folder inside `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. How I see this file inside the internal app folder.

Comment: What android version your device has?

Comment: Are you sure the file is downloaded?

Comment: @Homen yes its downloaded. I am getting this message alert('file downloaded successfully');

Comment: Are you checking in the internal memory folder?

Comment: yes into internal memory...

Comment: Use `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` instead of `cordova.file.dataDirectory` . Then you will get inside that folder

Comment: please any update for the same

Comment: So you already able to download the file.After download what you want to do?

Comment: I am able to download the file but I can not see the image @path /android/data/com.appname/files/...

Comment: Are you want to confirm that file is download or what?Means it downloaded successfully.So why you want to see the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `cordova.file.dataDirectory`. In real device you can not access this folder using file manager/third party application. This is for security reason. If you want to see the downloaded file then use `cordova.file.externalDataDirectory` instead of `cordova.file.dataDirectory` . Then you can see the file inside application folder which is located inside internal memory.

Comment: for the security reason I just want to download the files into app folder using cordova.file.dataDirector not into cordova.file.externalDataDirectory. I am able to download files but I can not see where its downloaded.

Comment: I know you downloaded.You can not see that folder.It is inside application's sandbox.

Comment: Yes your are correct I cant see the "ChatApp" folder inside application's sandbox

Comment: How you fixed this issue ? i am also unable to see file in IOS devices using this cordova.file.dataDirectory

Answer (score 1):

my case working  only below syntax

```
cordova.file.externalRootDirectory
```

Below two  syntax not working for me

already had(not working)

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory
```

above answare(not working)

```
cordova.file.externalDataDirectory
```

i am using capacitor version 2.0.0